# change velocity direction not work

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

i have a problem with the velocity change of my body.
Normaly the linearVelocity is 3f, and when the body collides with a wall the velocity shoud change at -3f. But when it does it goes around 0.

Here's the code:

```
private void createPlayer(){
...
bdef.velocity.set(-3f,0);
...
}

private void render(){
...
world.step(V.STEP, V.VELOCITYITERATIONS, V.POSITIONITERATIONS);
    if(cHandler.changeVelocity())
  ball.getBody().setLinearVelocity(-ball.getBody().getLinearVelocity().x,   0);
...
    }
```

i've already try it in beginContact, endContact, presolve and endsolve but always it is about 0.

And when i put the collision detection in beginContact and set it manually to -3f then it is -3f but the jumping does not work anymore correctly, i mean the gravity do not grab the ball anymore to the ground.

when i set it manually:

```
if(cHandler.changeVelocity()){
        ball.getBody().setLinearVelocity(-3f, 0);
    }
```

the log before:

```
velocityX: 3.0022564 velocityY: -5.261436
```

and after:

```
velocityX: -3.0 velocityY: 0.0
```

p.s the world gravity is (0, -10)
i hope you can help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Any reason you don't want box2d to handle the collision for you?  It will produce the result you're looking for. You don't need to detect a collision and manually change the velocity box2d will apply the collision force for you.

Comment: that does'nt work because the ball shoud continius move to right/left and when i set a restitution it bounce ok, but it go further to right and DOES NOT CHANCE from right to left... or how you mean to do this?

Comment: In BeginContact you can make a note of which way the velocity is going when the collision starts. Then in EndContact, you can set the velocity to be the reverse of that.

Comment: This might demonstrate what I mean, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.johnathongoss.libgdxtests click box2d after the app runs then you can throw the bodies around.